# How to store same time stamp in two tables at same time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a newbie and using **mysql**. I have two table **products** and **customers** and there is a column DATE in both the table which stores the **current timestamp** whenever the record is **modified**.
Now I have to update a row in both the tables but I want the **CURRENT timestamp** to be stored same in both the tables. I have found that **UPDATE does not** take multiple table names at the same time. 
I know that this must be simple but I have no idea how to do it. May be I am unable to identify the logic to do it.
Thanks for helping me out and sorry for the lame question :-p

Comment: Do you perform a batch update or a simple row update?

Comment: Simple row update sir

Answer (score 2):

Use a procedure

```
delimiter |
CREATE PROCEDURE updatewithtime(IN inputid int)
BEGIN      
    set @timestamp := now();
    update products set date = @imestamp where id = inputid;
    update customers set date = @imestamp where id = inputid;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

You can call that like this

```
call updatewithtime(123);
```

Comment: Don't forget to include this into a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TableaA a INNER JOIN TableB b ON (a.id= b.id)
SET
 //set values
WHERE a.id= 100  AND b.id= 100
```

Note : You can not use `limit`.

Still i will prefer the way given by juergen d (Stored procedure)